# How to restrict/ignore all types of body parser errors from the express.js/node.js? uncaughtException/unhandledRejection are not working

Tags: node.js, express

If Session was aborted by the client and express.js/node.js will throw an unhandled error like "Error: error" so this need to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore errors in nodeJS.

If you doesnt treat the error, it will throw an exception and crash the application.

In case you really want to ignore errors, you can create a method that get error, and just console.log it.

If you posted some code, I could type it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

the error is not the custom error and sure that error is from express middleware.

The error message box popping after the request.emit and while trying parse the JSON. 
i could get errorbox as the image containg electron "appname" and "Error:error". 
with only this error quite difficult to figure where it is going wrong.

so as soon i have created express server.
handling with uncaughtExceptions and unhandledRejections but not helping.

Please tell me how to handle request aborted calls because on top of this trying to parse the response and then ending up this situation.

how to get control of it with express middleware while debugging.